# How do i add JMenuBar to the Screen Menu Bar in macOS

Tags: java, jmenubar

I'm developing an app for macOS. But when I try to add the `JMenuBar` to the `JFrame` instance it just adds the `JFrame` window Instead of the macOS screen menu bar.

I've tried Following [this Article](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/macos/) and it didn't work :

It just overlapped the application title bar with the `JMenuBar`.
I've read other articles online and still with no noticeable change.

JRE Info:

```
% javac --version
javac 17.0.4.1
```

JDK Info:

```
% java --version 
java 17.0.4.1 2022-08-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the linked article (https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/macos/).
This definitely works.

Make sure that you invoke following in your `main()` method before creating UI:

```
System.setProperty( "apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true" );
```

Make sure to use `JFrame.setJMenuBar(JMenuBar)` to add the menu bar to the frame.